# Partition list to sub lists in Java8

Tags: java, list, java-8

I'm wondering if there is any nice a way using Java 8 to do something like this:

```
int amount = 1000;
int firstIndex = 0;
int lastIndex = firstIndex + amount;
List<int> projectIdsList;

while (lastIndex < projectIdsList.size()){
        doSomethingWhitSubList(projectIdsList.subList(firstIndex, lastIndex));
        firstIndex = lastIndex;
        lastIndex = firstIndex + amount;
}
doSomethingWhitSubList(projectIdsList.subList(firstIndex,  projectIdsList.size());
```

Comment: what is `countOfBulk`? what sublist are you seeking in while and after that? are you sure not using the same index twice?

Comment: By mistake, I edited and changed the countOfBulk to amount.
The function "doSomethingWhitSubList" get list<int> as parameter and insert them to DB,
In order to avoid insert of many items in same query... thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can partition the list into sublist using [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html), and I'm not really sure about your intention after partition, but you can collect the sublist's into a list using [collect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-)

```
List<List<Integer>> subLists = IntStream.range(0,integers.size())
            .filter(i->i%amount == 0)
            .mapToObj(i->integers.subList(i,i+amount > integers.size() ? integers.size() : i+amount))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or you can also use [forEach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) for any operations after partitioning

```
IntStream.range(0,integers.size())
            .filter(i->i%amount == 0)
            .mapToObj(i->integers.subList(i,i+amount > integers.size() ? integers.size() : i+amount))
            .forEach(this::doSomethingWhitSubList);
```

Comment: what is it that your code is actually doing? what is the relevant call to `doSomethingWhitSubList...` here?

Comment: I want to show OP how to create sublists from a list using java-8, and I agree on the question not really clear output he required after partitioning @Naman

Comment: sorry if i can add something from me, instead iterating through entire stream of integers, calculate in from how many segments you will need  `segmentsCount = integers.size()/segmentSize +1` then use `segmentsCount`  when you create IntStream. it will be sligtly more calculations, but iotal execution time will be much quicker

also if you use `Math.min` to calculate end of your sublist it will be much more readable